# Why shouldn't one enable XG transactions?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datanucleus

XG transactions [must be explicitly enabled](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions) when using JPA/JDO. Why so?

Are there possible problems or side effects by enabling them?

Comment: Clearly the question is totally specific to the GAE/Datastore database, so you really ought to tag your question for that. JDO/JPA are simply APIs that pass data to that database

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/#Java_Cross_group_transactions)

> - An XG transaction that touches only a single entity group has exactly the same performance and cost as a single-group, non-XG
>     transaction.
> - In an XG transaction that touches multiple entity groups, operations cost the same as if they were performed in a non-XG
>     transaction, **but may experience higher latency**.

Answer (score 0):

The guys who develeloped the datastore push you to be conscient of the underlaying infrastructure. That's why you cannot generate indexes in production, or run cross entity group transactions by default. You have to know why you use both of these features, with the tradeoffs they imply.

See [@Jimmy Kane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1857292/jimmy-kane)'s answer for the performance aspect.

There is also a limitation on the number of entity groups (up to five) that can be "touched" by a XG transaction ([docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/#Java_Cross_group_transactions)):

> The transaction can be applied across a maximum of five entity groups, and will succeed as long as no concurrent transaction touches any of the entity groups to which it applies